# Guide to aerial or space data types and availability

Tags: data, remote-sensing, satellite, download, aerial-photography

I am overwhelmed by the variety of types of satellite and aerial data (images?) available online. For example, at the USGS Earth Explorer data page, I see AVHRR; CEOS;Ikonos and OrbView; EO-1; GLS; HCMM; LPDACC (which contains AirMOSS, ASTER, MODIS, SRTM, ...)

At different times, I am seeking data for different purposes. Sometimes I want clear, high-resolution images; other times it may be something else.

Is there a good guide to the aerial and satellite data products available for download? I would like to read about what data types are good for what mapping purposes, and then see references to tutorials or instructions on how to process/use the specific data type.

I use QGIS.

Comment: This is a large part of what makes up the field of remote sensing. Here's a good book common in undergrad remote sensing courses that covers much of this subject matter: http://www.amazon.com/Remote-Sensing-Interpretation-Thomas-Lillesand/dp/0470052457/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=515DUqp024L&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR130%2C160_&refRID=1QSPQGPPYAA6DR9CVJ73

Comment: Perhaps we should link the newest edition, the 7th, of Lillesand, Kiefer & Chipman: http://www.amazon.com/Remote-Sensing-Interpretation-Thomas-Lillesand/dp/111834328X/

Comment: I don't thing so. Last year we tried make same database for our teacher and we couldn't find something like this. Of course it's also important, if you are looking for some open-data or commertial data and location of images. You can find different imagery for USA and f.e. Kenya. ;-) I know, it's not soo usefull.